# Check if WinList() contains a certain title

Tags: autoit

I am listing all open windows using [`WinList()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinList.htm) to get window title and -handle in AutoIt.

I want to check if resulting array contains a specific title. What is the best way to do this? There is no `WinList().Contains("TitleName")` or something like that.

```
Local $aList = WinList()    ;Gets a list of Window Titles and IDs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I got it now:

```
For $i = 1 To $aList[0][0]
    If $aList[$i][0] = "Title/String you search for" Then
        MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", "MessageBox shows this text if title is in list.")
    EndIf
Next
```

Comment: Use [`ExitLoop`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/keywords/ExitLoop.htm) (after `MsgBox()`) if `For...To...Step...Next` -loop should stop after first match.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use something similar to what you wrote.

```
#include <Array.au3>
Opt("WinDetectHiddenText", 0) ;0=don't detect, 1=do detect
Opt("WinSearchChildren", 0) ;0=no, 1=search children also
Opt("WinTextMatchMode", 1) ;1=complete, 2=quick
Opt("WinTitleMatchMode", 1) ;1=start, 2=subStr, 3=exact, 4=advanced, -1 to -4=Nocase
Local $title = 'AutoIt Help (v3.3.14.2)'
Local $aList = WinList()
;~ _ArrayDisplay($aList)
Local $iIndex = _ArraySearch($aList,$title)
WinActivate($aList[$iIndex][1], '')
```

Answer (score -1):

### Window exists?

> "*I am listing all open windows … I want to check if … contains a specific title. What is the best way to do this?*"

As per [Documentation - Function Reference - `WinExists()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinExists.htm) :

> Checks to see if a specified window exists.

Example.

```
Global Const $g_sWndTitle = 'Window title here'

If WinExists($g_sWndTitle) Then WinFlash($g_sWndTitle)
```

### Retrieve window handle, -text and -title

#### Handle

> "… *to get window title and -handle* …"

As per [Documentation - Function Reference - `WinGetHandle()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinGetHandle.htm) :

> Retrieves the internal handle of a window.

Example:

```
Global Const $g_sWndTitle = 'Window title here'
Global       $g_hWnd

If WinExists($g_sWndTitle) Then

    $g_hWnd = WinGetHandle($g_sWndTitle)
    WinFlash($g_hWnd)

EndIf
```

#### Text

As per [Documentation - Function Reference - `WinGetText()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinGetText.htm) :

> Retrieves the text from a window.

Example:

```
Global Const $g_sWndTitle = 'Window title here'

If WinExists($g_sWndTitle) Then

    WinFlash($g_sWndTitle)
    ConsoleWrite(WinGetText($g_sWndTitle) & @CRLF)

EndIf
```

#### Title

Likewise, [`WinGetTitle()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinGetTitle.htm).