# Looping through WinList() result takes much time

Tags: window, autoit, detection

I get a list of open windows and check if it contains a certain title. It is working but takes more than 10 seconds. Why does it take so long, what is wrong with my code?

Looks like `WinList()` doesn't list only visible windows.

```
$title = 0
$begintime = TimerInit()
MsgBox($MB_OK, "Timer", "Timer inicialized")

While $title = 0

    $aList = WinList()

    For $x = 1 To $aList[0][0]

        ;Check if a window with this title exists.
        if $aList[$x][0] = "WindowTitle" Then

            If $lastruntitle = "WindowTitle" Then

                $title = 1
                ExitLoop(2)

            Else

                SendMail4()
                $lastruntitle = "WindowTitle"
                $title = 1
                ExitLoop(2)

            EndIf

        EndIf

    Next

WEnd
```

Comment: Do you open the necessary window after start of the script or a window already openly at the time of start?  If you really need to use `While` loop,  you must add some `sleep` as least `sleep(100)`, othertwice cpu will be overloaded. Also show SendMail4() function.

Comment: "*Why does it take so long, what is wrong with my code?*" Use [`WinExists()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinExists.htm) or [`WinGetHandle()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinGetHandle.htm) to check for window's existence. [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50969300/4157124).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution for your task is:

```
#include <Array.au3>

While 1
   $aList = WinList()
   _ArraySearch($aList, "WindowTitle", 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
   If Not @error Then
      MsgBox(0,"","Window found!")
      Exit
   EndIf
   Sleep(100)
WEnd
```